# When was President Ellis elected?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

If he was President of the United States during the events of Iron Man 3 in 2013, was he elected or re-elected in November 2012?

Also, what else do we know about him or about other U.S. Presidents in the MCU?

**Update 9/29/15:** Was that President Ellis in episode S3E1 of Agents of SHIELD?

> [Yes.](http://screencrush.com/agents-of-shield-season-3-premiere-review/)

Comment: Not sure, but it's important to remember that MCU elections might follow a different cycle than ours.  For example, the elections in *The West Wing* were offset by 2 years (1998, 2002, 2004, etc).

Comment: I believe the elections in House of Cards don't line up either, but not sure.

Comment: @Paulster2: I believe in the very first episode of House of Cards (the American version, at least), they’re celebrating New Year’s Eve 2012 and the recent election of their President. That would match up with reality.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have no solid information on when President Matthew Ellis was elected.

However, we do know that he was President in 2013, when *Iron Man 3* was set.

Additionally, thanks to a quote in in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* found in the Smithsonian that reads "Welcome back, Cap" by President Ellis, we can assume that he was President at the time of Steve Rogers' defrosting in 2011.

If we assume that the elections in the Marvel Cinematic Universe follow real world dates, that would mean that in order for Matthew Ellis to be in office for both of these events, he would have had to have been elected in the 2008 election, and then re-elected for his second term in the 2012 election. Logically, that means that after 2016 we should be seeing a new President in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

---

Edit: As of the *Agents of SHIELD* season 3 episode "Bouncing Back", we know that Matthew Ellis is still the President of the United States in March 2016.

Comment: This came up on [a related question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125512) — are we sure the “Welcome back, Cap” quote is from 2011? Or might President Ellis have welcomed him back after his actual defrosting? (We at least know that the initial plan was to ease Cap back in gently, from the little 1940s charade into which he wakes up.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No, we have no definitive proof that the quote in question was from 2011, when Cap was defrosted. However, if there was another President in office at the time, wouldn't it be they who was quoted instead?

Comment: @DrDizzle: oh yeah, I’m just saying the quote wasn’t necessarily given right when Cap was defrosted. Maybe he was a secret until the Battle of New York, and then President Ellis welcomed him back at some public ceremony afterwards.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite After rewatching *Captain America: The First Avenger*, I noticed that the first thing that Steve does on waking up is run directly into the middle of Times Square. Even if SHIELD did intend to keep him a secret, the evidence would suggest that they failed to do so.

Comment: he does indeed — but imagine if, say, [Glenn Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glenn_Miller) ran past you in Times Square (or your equivalent local plaza). Would you recognise him? I don’t think his little Manhattan jog necessarily means that he would have to be immediately re-introduced to the public at large. Whereas after the Battle of New York, where he very publicly helped save lives and inspired people (as evidenced by the news reports), he would definitely be a big deal in the mainstream consciousness.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You're forgetting that SHIELD surround him when he's out, effectively drawing attention to him in a very public area while Nick Fury talks to him. To me, it seems like that incident is making the news no matter what - it wouldn't take long to figure out that the mystery man in the middle is one of this version of the USA's most iconic heroes.

Comment: I forget nothing! You’re totally right, it might make the news. But the part we see literally lasts like 30 seconds, and SHIELD are involved. I think it’s conceivable that they *could* keep that off the news, and that they’d want to.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite True, but we're firmly in the realm of "if" and "maybe" now. Until there is proof to the contrary, I'm happy to assume that President Ellis was in office in 2011 thanks to the presence of his "Welcome back, Cap" quote, although I understand my evidence is hardly bulletproof.

Comment: sure, I know what you mean. It’s at least equally plausible that Cap’s return was made public soon after he woke up.