# Is Obama part of MCU or not?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, luke-cage-2016, luke-cage

During episode 11 of the new Marvel/Netflix Series *Luke Cage* the main antagonist Diamondback tells a goon in reference to councilman Boone to

> Take Diet Obama upstairs (03:24).

As pointed out in the comments, this is only one of several instances (for link to report see below).

So, I've seen [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125512/when-did-the-marvel-cinematic-universe-u-s-presidential-history-diverge-from-th) about President Ellis, and am now wondering: Luke Cage definitely seems like a part of the MCU, as there's plenty of cross-references and the titular hero already appeared in *Jessica Jones*. Is President Obama therefore part of the MCU now as well? If so, when was his presidency? Is he possibly the predecessor of Matthew Ellis? Otherwise, that reference seems a little out of place for a gangster in New York: It's not very likely that his men, who probably come from the street and didn't receive a whole lot of education, would know of a senator from Chicago, correct?

Might be an error by the writers, too...

Comment: http://screenrant.com/luke-cage-president-obama-ellis/ - Fan theories, Ahoy!

Comment: Yeah, I like the theory that Obama was president from 2008 to roughly 2012, and resigned after the Chitauri invasion (well, presidents have resigned for less). Now we’re good until someone mentions President Clinton in *Infinity Wars* or something....

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the link!

Comment: @styks - Not enough to flesh out an answer, but helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Possible dupe of [When did the Marvel Cinematic Universe U.S. presidential history diverge from the real world's?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125512/when-did-the-marvel-cinematic-universe-u-s-presidential-history-diverge-from-th?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: He could, of course, be America’s most famous Senator in the MCU.

Answer (score 16):

We know very little, since there was exactly one throw-away line in one show, but since (until we know otherwise) *Luke Cage* occurs in the same universe as all the other MCU shows, we know that Obama was not president *during Luke Cage*, as you pointed out: the president at the time as Matthew Ellis.

We have no idea who was president before him (in fact, I don't think we know anything about any previous MCU presidents), but his own speech strongly implies that he was elected in 2012, in response to the Battle of New York. This gives us two possibilities:

- President Obama's term was from 2008-2012. The Battle of New York and Ellis strong stance on it got Ellis elected in place of Obama's second term.
- *Senator* Obama is a senator from Chicago that ran for president but did not win. If, as an example, Obama became the first African American major-party presidential candidate, even if he lost, he would likely be a pop-culture figure for a while. If you were alive in the 80s, you probably still remember Geraldine Ferarro, the first ever female major-party vice presidential candidate; even though she lost, it was an historic event, and her name was widely recognized for years afterward.

---

On a side note.. the mainsteam Marvel 616 timeline has always used the "real world" president, so in that case President Obama is, in fact, President until 2016.